# Counting initial bits of 0 in Java

Tags: java, bitwise

I want to count the number of bits set to 0 at the beginning of a byte array. So far the code I have is this:

```java
    public static int getPrefixLength(byte[] bytes) {

        int prefixLength = 0;

        for (byte b : bytes) {
            if (b == 0) {
                prefixLength += 8; // 1 byte = 8 bits
            } else {
                int tmp = 0;
                for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if ((b & (1 << i)) == 0) {
                        tmp++;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                prefixLength += tmp;
            }
        }

        return prefixLength;
    }
```

How can I improve this?

Comment: How and why is this function called?

Comment: I have a Item class and each item has an ID which is a byte array. Then, I have a Item array and the index in which I store the item is the prefix length (e.g. if the prefix is 7 bits long, the item will be stored in the 7th index of the array)

Comment: How wide is the ID? i.e., how many bytes are there?

Comment: 160 bits, 20 bytes

Comment: Does this produce correct results?  For example, for `{0, 1, 0}` it would return 23.  Is that what is wanted?  Or should it return 15?

Answer (score 1):

Let's split it in two:

```
/**
 * Calculates the number of bits that are zero in the byte array from the left hand side.
 * The leftmost byte is the one with index zero, the leftmost bits in each byte are the most significant bits.
 * @param bytes the byte array containing bytes.length * Byte.SIZE bits
 * @return the number of leading zero bits 
 */
public static int numberOfLeadingZeroBits(byte[] bytes) {
    int numberOfLeadingZeros = 0;
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        if (b == 0) {
            numberOfLeadingZeros += Byte.SIZE;
        } else {
            return numberOfLeadingZeros + numberOfLeadingZeroBits(b);
        }
    }
    return numberOfLeadingZeros;
}

// TODO similar API description in JavaDoc    
public static int numberOfLeadingZeroBits(byte b) {
    for (int i = Byte.SIZE - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (((b >> i) & 1) == 1) {
            return Byte.SIZE - 1 - i;
        }
    }
    return Byte.SIZE;
}
```

Note that we can immediately return once we have the number of zero bits of the byte - as obviously we would have to stop execution.

I've renamed the methods as `getPrefixLength` doesn't indicate to the user what the prefix is supposed to be.

Just for fun I moved the bit in byte `b` instead of performing a mask. It really doesn't matter much, but sometimes it is fun to see some alternatives.

If performance is an issue it is possible to inline the second method - but I would strongly prefer not to.

---

Furthermore, you could do a one-liner, which - mind you - will perform a copy of the entire byte array:

```
int numberOfLeadingZeroBits = bytes.length * Byte.SIZE - new BigInteger(1, bytes).bitLength();
```

---

I always use `Byte.SIZE` instead of e.g. 8, because it greatly clarifies what the number represents in the code. It might be slightly faster to create a local `private static final int BITS_IN_BYTE = 8` value, if speed is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

If your representation allows for it, iterating over 64-bit longs packing 8 bytes each will be faster than iterating per byte. If you need to convert to this representation from your byte array (perhaps using `ByteBuffer`), the conversion cost may outweigh any performance benefit. Measure this for your specific scenario. Since your ID array is actually 20 bytes, even having 5x 32-bit integers or a mix of int and long could work.

Replace your inner bit-twiddling loop with a call to the built-in [numberOfLeadingZeros](https://devdocs.io/openjdk%7E18/java.base/java/lang/long#numberOfLeadingZeros(long)). This will be simple and fast. If you absolutely need to sacrifice legibility and simplicity in the name of speed, there are [faster, more complicated methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305059/how-do-you-calculate-log-base-2-in-java-for-integers).

In my tests, there is a slight performance improvement to using `numberOfLeadingZeros`; its biggest benefit is simplicity. Packing is much more effectual in reducing execution time. If I had to pick a favourite, it would be the 5x 32-bit int version for its uniformity of representation and execution efficiency.

### Timing fixture

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HexFormat;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.lang.System.nanoTime;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Main {
    private static final IdParser[] parsers = {
        new IntLongParser(),
        new BuiltinIntParser(),
        new BuiltinBytesParser(),
        new OldBytesParser(),
    };

    private static abstract class IdParser {
        private static final HexFormat format = HexFormat.of();

        public ID parse(String str) {
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(format.parseHex(str));
            return construct(buf);
        }

        protected abstract ID construct(ByteBuffer buf);
    }

    private static class OldBytesParser extends IdParser {
        protected ID construct(ByteBuffer buf) {
            return new OldBytesID(buf.array());
        }
    }

    private static class BuiltinBytesParser extends IdParser {
        protected ID construct(ByteBuffer buf) {
            return new BuiltinBytesID(buf.array());
        }
    }

    private static class BuiltinIntParser extends IdParser {
        protected ID construct(ByteBuffer buf) {
            IntBuffer ibuf = buf.asIntBuffer();
            int[] array = new int[ibuf.capacity()];
            ibuf.get(array);
            return new BuiltinIntID(array);
        }
    }

    private static class IntLongParser extends IdParser {
        protected ID construct(ByteBuffer buf) {
            IntLongID id = new IntLongID(
                buf.getLong(),
                buf.getLong(),
                buf.getInt()
            );
            if (buf.hasRemaining())
                throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected data while parsing ID");
            return id;
        }
    }

    private static abstract class ID {
        public abstract int prefixLen();
    }

    private static class OldBytesID extends ID {
        private final byte[] id;
        public OldBytesID(byte[] id) { this.id = id; }

        public int prefixLen() {
            int prefixLength = 0;

            for (byte b: id) {
                if (b == 0) {
                    prefixLength += 8; // 1 byte = 8 bits
                } else {
                    int tmp = 0;
                    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
                        if ((b & (1 << i)) == 0) {
                            tmp++;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    prefixLength += tmp;
                }
            }

            return prefixLength;
        }
    }

    private static class BuiltinBytesID extends ID {
        private final byte[] id;
        public BuiltinBytesID(byte[] id) { this.id = id; }

        public int prefixLen() {
            int prefix = 0;

            for (byte b: id) {
                if (b == 0)
                    prefix += 8;
                else
                    return prefix + Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(b << 24);
            }

            return prefix;
        }
    }

    private static class BuiltinIntID extends ID {
        private final int[] id;
        public BuiltinIntID(int[] id) { this.id = id; }

        public int prefixLen() {
            int prefix = 0;

            for (int i: id) {
                if (i == 0)
                    prefix += 32;
                else
                    return prefix + Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(i);
            }

            return prefix;
        }
    }

    private static class IntLongID extends ID {
        private final long l1, l2;
        private final int i3;
        public IntLongID(long l1, long l2, int i3) {
            this.l1 = l1; this.l2 = l2; this.i3 = i3;
        }

        public int prefixLen() {
            if (l1 != 0)
                return Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(l1);
            if (l2 != 0)
                return Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(l2) + 64;
            return Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(i3) + 128;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ID> ids = Arrays.stream(parsers)
            .map(p -> p.parse(args[0]))
            .toList();

        // We need to stripe the time trials, because the first few iterations are
        // slower while the CPU spins up and/or the OS thread scheduler allocates
        // more time.
        final int stripeSize = 1_000, iterations = 10_000;

        Map<String, Double> times = new HashMap<>();
        for (ID id: ids)
            times.put(id.getClass().getSimpleName(), 0d);

        // Save (even though we overwrite) the prefix results, to prevent the
        // inner operation from being optimised away.
        Map<String, Long> prefixes = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            for (ID id: ids) {
                String name = id.getClass().getSimpleName();
                Result result = timePrefix(id, stripeSize);
                times.put(name, times.get(name) + result.time);
                prefixes.put(name, result.prefix);
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Long> kv: prefixes.entrySet()) {
            out.printf(
                "%20s: prefix=%d time=%.1f ns%n",
                kv.getKey(), kv.getValue(),
                times.get(kv.getKey()) / iterations);
        }
    }

    private record Result(long prefix, double time) { }

    private static Result timePrefix(ID id, int stripeSize) {
        long prefix = 0;

        long start = nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < stripeSize; i++)
            prefix += id.prefixLen();
        double dur = ((double)(nanoTime() - start))/stripeSize;

        return new Result(prefix/stripeSize, dur);
    }
}
```

### Output

When this is passed:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000002
```

i.e. an almost-worst-case two bits short of being empty, we get:

```
           IntLongID: prefix=158 time=13.4 ns
        BuiltinIntID: prefix=158 time=19.4 ns
      BuiltinBytesID: prefix=158 time=37.1 ns
          OldBytesID: prefix=158 time=39.4 ns
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the `else` blocks by using some simple transformations

#### Outer if

- You can use `continue` to get rid of `else if`

```
for (byte inputByte : bytes) {
    if (inputByte == 0) {
        prefixLength += 8;
        continue;
    }

    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    ...
    }

}
```

#### Inner if

- You can invert the if statement and call the `break` there

```
for (int bitShifter = 7; bitShifter >= 0; bitShifter--) {
    if ((inputByte & (1 << bitShifter)) != 0) {
        break;
    }
    prefixLength++;
}
```

#### All together

```
int prefixLength = 0;

for (byte inputByte : bytes) {
    if (inputByte == 0) {
        prefixLength += 8;
        continue;
    }

    for (int bitShifter = 7; bitShifter >= 0; bitShifter--) {
        if ((inputByte & (1 << bitShifter)) != 0) {
            break;
        }
        prefixLength++;
    }
}

return prefixLength;
```

Answer (score -1):

The main problem with this code is that it doesn't solve the problem.

The code you've posted simply counts the number of 0 bits, which is not the same as counting the number of **initial** zero bits.

Make your code work, **test** that it works, and come back and ask for a second review.

Comment: This isn't quite true either.  It's true that it counts all the 0 bits in all the zero bytes.  But in a non-zero byte, it only counts the initial bits.  E.g. `{0, 2, 0}` returns 22 and `{0, 64, 0}` returns 17, even though there are 23 0 bits in both.  Given the problem description, I think that it should return 14 and 9 respectively instead.  But perhaps it is the problem description that is wrong, not the code.  Or perhaps there is something about the input that keeps that from ever happening.  E.g. `{0, 2, -1}` will return 14 as I would expect.